# Random matlab matrix with at least .4 and at most .6 ones per column

Tags: matlab, random

I'm creating a matrix in matlab of size n that contains only ones and zeros. The easiest way to do that is round(rand(m,n)) for a matrix of size mxn, but it creates in some cases rows that have all zeros or all ones. I want to put a lower and upper bound in the number of ones that each row has. Is there an easy way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is just for one column, but can easily be extended to a matrix:

```
v = zeros(m,1); % column
```

Fill the beginning of the column with at least 40% and at most 60% ones:

```
v(1: floor((0.4+(0.6-0.4)*rand())*(m+1))) = 1;
```

Shuffle the column:

```
v = v(randperm(numel(v)));
```

Comment: I ran it and it always creates 5 ones.

Comment: But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JosuéOrtega What size of `m` did you use?

Comment: @LuisMendo Sure, thanks!